# Why is C1 requesting my admin page remotely?

Tags: c1-cms

Some time ago I had Composite C1 installed on a public url to test it (for example http://c1.mydomain.com). But I did remove it already some time ago.
I checked my firewall logs recently and I discovered requests for http://c1.mydomain.com/Composite/top.aspx every single night from IP address 109.238.52.32. (Composite.net's ip address is 109.238.52.24, which is almost the same, so I assume the requests are comming from Composite.net.)

So the question is: Why is Composite.net requesting my admin page every single day?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a process that check long-term usage of the software in order to generate statistics. The daily URL request looks at the HTTP status code (HTTP 200 vs other) to determine if your website is still online and using the CMS. Since the URL is unique and likely not used by any other system it is a good indication.

When that is said it is probably silly to keep on requesting the same URL once the check starts reporting 404 or similar.